# unable to read pdf buffer in react.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, bufferedreader

this is what i got the response from my express server

[image: i got the response from my express server]

then i parse the pdf file buffer to read the pdf from the brower

using **new Blob() and  window.URL.createObjectURL()**

```
const file = new Blob(product.msds.data,{type:"application/pdf"});

const getFile = file && window.URL.createObjectURL(file);

             <a
                href={getFile}
                target="_blank"
                rel="noopener noreferrer"
                type="application/pdf"
              >
                click to show pdf
              </a>
            </>
```

[image: then i parse the pdf file buffer]

and when i open the created link, the browser has failed to load PDF document

[image: and when i open the created link, the browser has failed to load PDF document]

thanks for your upcoming solution!

Comment: Please make this a [mcve]

Comment: Code as text is more helpful to us than pictures. Be sure to include sufficient details so we can understand it. There should be no undeclared variables, for example. See the link SuperStormer gave for tips on how to create a good code example.

Comment: can you guys able to understand it now?

Comment: Can you post the pdf data? My guess is that its probably incorrect.

Comment: it is just a list of array data: [37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46, 52, 10, 37, 211, 235, 233, 225, 10, 49, 32, 48, 32, 111, 98, 106, 10, 60,…]
type: "Buffer"

Comment: I know it is an array; however, the reason why the browser can't display it is probably because it isn't a valid pdf.

Comment: i already checked my pdf data and it is valid

Answer (score 0):

let's check this

```
const bytes = new Uint8Array(product.msds.data) 
    
const blob= new Blob([bytes], {type: "application/pdf"});
    
let link = document.createElement('a');
    
link.href= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    
link.download="myFileName.pdf";
    
link.click();
```

I hope these codes will help you guys

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.